# Why i'm getting 403 error while creating a docker image?

Tags: django, docker, docker-compose, celery, docker-image

Dockerfile:

```
FROM python:3.19-alpine

WORKDIR /app

ENV PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE 1
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1
ENV PATH="/PY/BIN:$PATH"

RUN pip install --upgrade pip

COPY ./req.txt /app/req.txt
COPY . /app

RUN pip install -r req.txt
```

docker-compose.yml:

```
version: '3.8'

services:
  django:
    container_name: django_celery_project
    build:
      context: ./
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    command: sh -c "python manage.py migrate && python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000"
    volumes:
      - .:/app
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
    environment:
      - ALLOWED_HOSTS=localhost,127.0.0.1
      - DEBUG=True
      - SECRET_KEY=***********
```

command :
**docker-compose up -d --build**

result :

=> [django internal] load .dockerignore                                                                           0.0s
=> => transferring context: 87B                                                                                   0.0s
=> [django internal] load build definition from Dockerfile                                                        0.0s
=> => transferring dockerfile: 270B                                                                               0.0s
=> ERROR [django internal] load metadata for docker.io/library/python:3.19-alpine                                10.7s
=> [django auth] library/python:pull token for registry-1.docker.io                                               0.0s

error :
failed to solve: python:3.19-alpine: failed to authorize: failed to fetch oauth token: unexpected status from POST request to https://auth.docker.io/token: ***403 Forbidden***

My IP address without a VPN is: 93.115.225.147

My IP address with VPN is: 213.142.149.230

Comment: Hi, I think you mispelled a version of Python, since 3.19 doesn't exist. You could check available python versions on Docker hub here: https://hub.docker.com/_/python

Comment: you are right. this is true -> FROM python:alpine3.19 . but it doesn't solve the problem.

Comment: Python `3.19` doesn't exist. If you want to pull the latest one try `FROM python:3.12-alpine`. Here is a list of python releases: https://www.python.org/doc/versions/#in-development-versions

Comment: https://hub.docker.com/layers/library/python/alpine3.19/images/sha256-ae1f508f01ac1806e84c68b43ee0983b586426dfa39f5d21eced0dd7f5e230f4?context=explore


its python:alpine3.19 not python3.19

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this problem by pulling the python:alpine3.19 from the command line with this command :

**docker pull python:alpine3.19**

and then I ran the " **docker-compose up -d --build** " once again and the image was built properly.

Iranians should use a VPN throughout the process.